# Trying to Parse nested JSON file in After Effects scripting

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, adobe, after-effects

can someone show me what I am doing wrong here? I have a json file that I am parsing through a script in After Effects, and I'm not sure how to iterate through the section of the json file.

My json file is:

```
{
    "Timestamp": "20-Sep-2020 12:38:07.177",
    "m11": 0.2202,
    "m12": 0.8858,
    "m13": 0.4085,
    "m21": -0.9708,
    "m22": 0.2399,
    "m23": 0.0031,
    "m31": -0.0952,
    "m32": -0.3972,
    "m33": 0.9128,
    "qX": -0.13,
    "qY": 0.1635,
    "qZ": -0.6026,
    "qW": -0.7702
  },
  {
    "Timestamp": "20-Sep-2020 12:38:07.186",
    "m11": 0.2204,
    "m12": 0.8861,
    "m13": 0.4078,
    "m21": -0.9708,
    "m22": 0.2401,
    "m23": 0.0031,
    "m31": -0.0952,
    "m32": -0.3965,
    "m33": 0.9131,
    "qX": -0.1297,
    "qY": 0.1632,
    "qZ": -0.6026,
    "qW": -0.7703
  }
```

And my jsx file is this:

```
#include "json2.js"

var file = new File;
var check = 0;

var mainWindow = new Window("palette", "File Reader", undefined);
mainWindow.orientatizzaaq1on = "column";

var groupOne = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");
groupOne.orientation = "row";
var fileLocBox = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "Selected File Location");
fileLocBox.size = [150, 20];
var getFileButton = groupOne.add("button", undefined, "File...");
getFileButton.helpTip = "Select a .json file to change the comp";

var groupTwo = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupTwo");
groupTwo.orientation = "row";
var applyButton = groupTwo.add("button", undefined, "Apply");

mainWindow.center();
mainWindow.show();

getFileButton.onClick = function() {
    file = file.openDlg("Open a file", "Acceptable Files:*.json");
    fileLocBox.text = file.fsName;
    check = 1;
    }

applyButton.onClick = function() {
        if(check == 0) {
                alert("Please select a file");
                return false;
            } else {
                //app.beginUndoGroup("Comp Changes");
                var fileExtension = fileLocBox.text;
                var fileData;
                
                if(fileExtension.substring(fileExtension.length-4, fileExtension.length) == "json") {
                    fileData = readJson();
                    
                    changeComp(fileData);
                }
            alert("done");
   }
}
function readJson() {
    var currentLine;
    var jsonStuff = [];
    file.open("r");
        while(!file.eof) {
                currentLine = file.readln();
                jsonStuff.push(currentLine);
            }
        file.close();
        jsonStuff = jsonStuff.join("");
        var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonStuff);
        
        return parsedJson;
    }

function changeComp(data) {
    var nullz = app.project.activeItem.layers.addNull();
    nullz.threeDLayer = true;
    nullz.name = "parent to me";
    var size = Object.keys(data).length;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var temp =data[1].m11; 
        var t =i/25;
       nullz.xRotation.setValueAtTime(t, temp);
      }
  }
```

I have a feeling my json file may need to be formatted differently, this is just how it came to me from another app.

So the idea is it will go through the json file, get the "m11" value, apply it to the null's rotation, then go on to the next frame, grab the next "m11" and so on...
In my script, if I just say:

```
var temp =data.m11; 
var t =i/25;
nullz.xRotation.setValueAtTime(t, temp);
```

It works and will grab the value of the first "m11" and apply it to the null object.
But if I try to get to the second "m11" by saying

```
var temp =data[1].m11;
```

or

```
var temp =data.m11[1];
```

it doesn't work, so just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong?
Is it the way the json is formatted?
The json originally came with [] at the end and beginning, but leaving those in would cause the script to crash when it tried to read the file, taking them out make it somewhat work, as I mentioned above.

Or is it the script? Or both, I'm guessing?

Comment: I think it might be a problem with how you are reading the json file. This  https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/ might be helpfule

Comment: thanks for this, though I'm not sure it adds anything- the example  they give is what I am already able to accomplish, reading from the first set of {}, they don't have a second set of {} or explain how you would target a second set.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your exact environment, but it seems like you removed the brackets [] that would have made the json contain an array. If you parsed it as an array this would work:

```
function changeComp(data) {
    var nullz = app.project.activeItem.layers.addNull();
    nullz.threeDLayer = true;
    nullz.name = "parent to me";

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const value = data[i].m11;
        const time = i / 25;
        nullz.xRotation.setValueAtTime(time, value);
   }
}
```

Also could you elaborate more on your problem?
When you write:

> "But if I try to get to the second "m11" by saying (...) it doesn't
> work"

What doesn't work? What was the error code? Reading what the computer says is wrong can usually help with finding what is wrong!

This is the file i parsed as data:

```
[
    {
        "Timestamp": "20-Sep-2020 12:38:07.177",
        "m11": 0.2202,
        "m12": 0.8858,
        "m13": 0.4085,
        "m21": -0.9708,
        "m22": 0.2399,
        "m23": 0.0031,
        "m31": -0.0952,
        "m32": -0.3972,
        "m33": 0.9128,
        "qX": -0.13,
        "qY": 0.1635,
        "qZ": -0.6026,
        "qW": -0.7702
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "20-Sep-2020 12:38:07.186",
        "m11": 0.2204,
        "m12": 0.8861,
        "m13": 0.4078,
        "m21": -0.9708,
        "m22": 0.2401,
        "m23": 0.0031,
        "m31": -0.0952,
        "m32": -0.3965,
        "m33": 0.9131,
        "qX": -0.1297,
        "qY": 0.1632,
        "qZ": -0.6026,
        "qW": -0.7703
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to look to find an error code? Where in After Effects is a console? It just won't finish the script, it won't add the data to the rotation as it's supposed to, it won't give the popup alert that says "done". I'm pretty sure I have tried it with the [] but data[i].m11 didn't work.. you are saying you think it should though, the line is properly written? I wasn't sure if adding [i] to 'data' was the correct way to reach it.

Comment: @BrianWilliams Yupp if you parsed the json with the array it would work with the code i posted, i tested it.

If there are no error codes in AE you could log the data along to way so you can see what the program is doing. Adding `Alert( JSON.stringify(data) )` after parsing your data would let you see how your program has parsed the json file.